# rxjava using Single to pass a parameter in the doOnSuccess

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java

```
Java 8
io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.6
kotlin 1.2.21
```

I am trying to pass a parameter in the doOnSuccess using a Single.

However, I am getting an error, that I can't seem to solve.

```
class TranslateInteractor(val repository: Respository) {
    fun requestNetworkTranslated(message: String): Completable {
        return repository.fetchTranslation(message)
                .doOnSuccess { handleTranslationResponse(message, it) }.toCompletable()
    }

    private fun handleTranslationResponse(message, String, translatedResponse: TranslatedResponse) {
        saveTranslation(
                "",
                translatedResponse.content,
                translatedResponse.translationEngine)
    }

    private fun saveTranslation(message: String, content: String, engine: String) {
        /* Save to local storage */
    }
}
```

The error is in the .doOnSuccess. As I want to pass the message to the handleTranslationResponse.

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is String but TranslatedResponse was expected
```

How can I pass the message and what I get from the TranslatedResponse back to the HandleTranslationResponse?

The repository which is a java class that returns a single:

```
public class Respository {
    private NetworkAPI networkAPI;

    public Single<TranslatedResponse> fetchTranslation(final String message) {
        return networkAPI.fetchTranslation(new TranslateRequest(message));
    }
}
```

My Data classes in Kotlin are:

```
data class TranslatedResponse(
        val content: String,
        val translationEngine: String)
```

And request

```
data class TranslateRequest(val message: String)
```

For the networkAPI I have the following in java snippet:

```
public interface NetworkAPI {
    Single<TranslatedResponse> fetchTranslation(TranslateRequest request);
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Perhaps `{ handleTranslationResponse(it) }`?

Comment: I have changed the parameter as I need to pass the message to the handleTranslationResponse. So I have changed to `{handleTranslationResponse(message, it)}` Would that be correct to pass the message and the 'it'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't do that is because `doOnSucess` takes only one parameter, which is whatever the `Repository` returns.

You'll need to somehow add your original message to the response that the `Repository` returns. There are a couple of options (e.g. using a `Pair` or a new `data class`)

An example:

```
data class Translation(
    val originalMessage: String,
    val translatedMessage: TranslationResponse
)
```

Now your `Repository` becomes:

```
public class Respository {
    private NetworkAPI networkAPI;

    public Single<TranslatedResponse> fetchTranslation(final String message) {
        return new Translation(
            message,
            networkAPI.fetchTranslation(new TranslateRequest(message)
        );
    }
}
```

Finally, `handleTranslationResponse` now takes a `Translation` instead, which makes your interactor look like:

```
class TranslateInteractor(val repository: Respository) {
    fun requestNetworkTranslated(message: String): Completable {
        return repository.fetchTranslation(message)
                .doOnSuccess { handleTranslationResponse(it) }.toCompletable()
    }

    private fun handleTranslationResponse(translation: Translation) {
        saveTranslation(
            translation.originalMessage,
            translation.translatedMessage.content,
            translation.translatedMessage.translationEngine)
    }

    private fun saveTranslation(message: String, content: String, engine: String) {
        // do whatever you want!
    }
}
```